# Direct counter for the total daily votes

Tags: support, voting

Is there a direct counter where I can see the total daily votes (40 votes) without the need to subtract from the last vote given yesterday, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on your user profile (defaults to the Activity page if for your own user). A summary (by period and type) of voting is listed in the bottom-right of the profile page; here's mine on Meta.TeX.SE:

[image]

Clicking on "View more" will show you explicit voting actions (including up/down votes, closures, deletions, ...). A shortcut to this detailed view is available by clicking on the Votes Cast link in your profile (top-right):

[image]

Comment: Very kind Werner I see always the number of the votes cast and into my mind count 40 votes :-). Surely there is not down votes cast. :-) Thank you for your answer.